# How to find transaction info when it's not showing up in the explorers

Tags: pending-transactions

About an hour ago, I have deposited 0.05 ETH to this address: `0x1da075fd6816e5477125922282e540084e308be8`

The geth output shows:

`INFO [09-05|19:12:59] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x21da1d09b186e8929d29d945487ff0aba4efa09744b4ec082c4a7b1da45ddc23 recipient=0x1da075fd6816e5477125922282e540084e308be8`

---

**I have made this transaction using the official Ethereum Wallet, using "light sync".** I cannot find this transaction in any blockchain explorer, however the geth output clearly tells me the transaction was submitted. In the Ethereum Wallet UI, I also clearly saw my transaction pending (0/12 confirmations). However, I cannot find this information anymore in the wallet UI, no matter where I look. (I have restarted the wallet since).

I have tried the following explorers, none of them know about my transaction:

- EtherScan
- EtherChain
- EtherCamp

---

**How can I find out what happened to my transaction ?**

[image: Geth output]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried wiring some ETH from one of my accounts to another, in order to reproduce the issue, and noticed the following errors in the devtools of Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0:

**First, an error:**

`Unhandled rejection VersionError: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)`

**Then, it keeps polling the status**:

`Checking transaction 0x81...49d8f. Current confirmations: 0"`

**Second error after a while (10 mins):**

`The transaction from First account to Second account couldn't be successfully executed.`

---

Seems like this is related to a [bug](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2823#issuecomment-317788932) in the Ethereum Wallet. Downgrading *should* fix the issue, although I haven't tried yet.

Comment: You should edit your question if you need to add more info.